# Castle Windsor - Resolving a generic implementation to a base type

Tags: c#, generics, castle-windsor

I'm trying to use Windsor as a factory to provide specification implementations based on subtypes of `XAbstractBase` (an abstract message base class in my case).

I have code like the following:

```
public abstract class XAbstractBase { }
public class YImplementation : XAbstractBase { }
public class ZImplementation : XAbstractBase { }

public interface ISpecification<T> where T : XAbstractBase
{
    bool PredicateLogic();
}

public class DefaultSpecificationImplementation : ISpecification<XAbstractBase>
{
    public bool PredicateLogic() { return true; }
}

public class SpecificSpecificationImplementation : ISpecification<YImplementation>
{
    public bool PredicateLogic() { /*do real work*/ }
}
```

My component registration code looks like this:

```
container.Register(
    AllTypes.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .BasedOn(typeof(ISpecification<>))
    .WithService.FirstInterface()
)
```

This works fine when I try to resolve `ISpecification<YImplementation>`; it correctly resolves `SpecificSpecificationImplementation`.

However, when I try to resolve `ISpecification<ZImplementation>` Windsor throws an exception:

```
"No component for supporting the service ISpecification'1[ZImplementation, AssemblyInfo...] was found"
```

Does Windsor support resolving generic implementations down to base classes if no more specific implementation is registered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](http://kozmic.net/2010/03/11/advanced-castle-windsor-ndash-generic-typed-factories-auto-release-and-more/) post.

### Update

Ok, I see now what you're doing wrong. You have no service for `ISpecification<ZImplementation>`, hence it's not surprising that Windsor can't resolve it.

It's not a Windsor issue at all.

Comment: That was one of the better posts I found before I posted the question here.  What I'm looking for is whether it's possible to address the zero-or-more situation (the post only addresses the one-or-more situation, but I assume it would be trivial to add a default return value) using only Windsor's built-in facilities. If I have to write a factory anyway, I'm much more likely to just register it and inject it like normal.

Comment: Okay; I understand why it's not possible.  Thanks!

Comment: @adriaanp Link is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can register it as an open generic to provide a fallback, e.g.

```
public class DefaultSpecificationImplementation<T> : ISpecification<T>
    where T : XAbstractBase
{
    public bool PredicateLogic() { return true; }
}
```

as

```
Component.For(typeof(ISpecification<>))
    .ImplementedBy(DefaultSpecificationImplementation<>)
```

Then when Windsor can't find a specific implementation, it will use the generic one