# How to resolve a generic type in a Castle Windsor container that matches an object

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, castle-windsor

I have the following interfaces and classes.

```
interface ICommand { ... }

class Command1 : ICommand { ... }

class Command1 : ICommand { ... }

interface IHandle<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand
{
    IResult Handle(TCommand command);
}

Command1Handler : IHandle<Command1> { ... }

Command2Handler : IHandle<Command2> { ... }
```

Command1Handler and Command2Handler are registered in a Castle Widsor container. When I receive a command I would like to find the Handler in the container that can handle the command.

```
public IResult ProcessCommand(ICommand command)
{
    var handler = Container.Resolve //How to resolve based on command?
    return handler.Handle(command);
}
```

I can't call

```
Container.Resolve<IHandle<Command1>>()
```

since I dont know TCommand and if I do

```
Container.ResolveAll(typeof(IHandle<>))
```

I don't know which one of the handlers that can handle my command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Castle Windsor - Resolving a generic implementation to a base type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039296/castle-windsor-resolving-a-generic-implementation-to-a-base-type)

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to use reflection:

```
dynamic handler = container.Resolve(
    typeof(IHandler<>).MakeGenericType(cmd.GetType()));
handler.Handle(cmd);
```

But real answer is to refactor your code, you are fighting against type system. Windsor don't help here, it can get you reference to proper type but you still must cast to proper `IHandler<T>` when you are calling `Handle(cmd)`. It would be much better to have generic method:

```
void Handle<T>(ICommand<T> cmd) {
  var handler = container.Resolve<IHandler<T>>();
  handler.Handle(cmd);
}

interface ICommand<T> { }
class Command1 : ICommand<Command1> { }
```

or to use magic of polymorphism:

```
class BaseCommand<T> : ICommand<T> {
  public void FindAndExecuteHandler(IKernel kernel) {
    kernel.Resolve<IHandler<T>>().Handle(this);
  }
}

class Command1 : BaseCommand<Command1> { }

cmd1.FindAndExecuteHandler(container);
```

Very similar problem to yours is to find `IValidator<T>` for given model, there are many questions on SO with various solutions - you may want to do some R&D here.

Comment: I did som more refactoring instead and used a dispatcher where I registered functions instead of having interfaces. I didn't have the possibility to change the commands.